# HTML tags (i.e <p>) inside my angular brackets {{}}

Tags: wordpress, api, ionic-framework

I'm working in an angular app where the JSON documents i'm getting includes several object. But while fetching the posts contents it also includes the HTML tags `(i.e <p>)` inside my angular brackets `{{}}` the problem here is i want only the contents not the HTML tags. Either give me a solution to get rid of that  or  tell me how to use html tags inside `{{<p> hello <p>}}` . I want to get an output of angular to show the paragraphed "hello" instead of `<p>hello<p>`.

Give me a solution to ge an output as **hello** instead of `<p>hello<p>`

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response!

I Used the angular binding ng-bind. That working fine for me. I've used 
`<p ng-bind-html="post.name"></p>` . Now the problems solved :)

Comment: Nice, an Angular solution is best

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a 'best practice' solution for this, I don't think angular is currently handling this. Try using a function that strips the html tags like this:

```
{{stripInput(inputObject)}}

stripInput(html) {
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript). Some other good answers are there if this doesn't work :)